# limit count to count just 10 last days

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to limit my count of type 1 grouped by home name in table results by 10 by datum (date), but its still count all my rows in table. I always got full count in all rows. I need limit count to last 10 days of datum column.

```
Select home,count,STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') as datum FROM 
(select *,count(*) as count,STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') as datum 
from results where type='1' 
group by home order by count(fix) desc LIMIT 1) as full 
order by datum desc limit 10
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question although it would make things simpler - why are you storing date as a string field not a date field?

Comment: `WHERE datum BETWEEN date1 AND date2`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I cannot tell what this query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i need to calculate last 10, i dont know which will be date1 and date2.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i cannot, because its a script who is putting dates from text to mysql text column so i need to sort like that.
Or i can try to modify script to import to data column but i didn't success with that.